# Passing a string to a C library from OCaml using Ctypes and Foreign

Tags: ocaml, ctypes, pcap

I'm really new to OCaml, and wanted to try and do some work with pcap as a way of getting started, only, there doesn't seem to be a maintained library for it. After looking at the awesome Real World OCaml book, I figured I'd give writing a binding a go.

Here's the (poor) code snippet:

```
open Ctypes
open Foreign
open PosixTypes
let char_ptr = "                 "

let pcap_lookupdev = foreign "pcap_lookupdev" (string @-> returning string_opt)

let result = pcap_lookupdev char_ptr

let test2 =
    match result with
    | None -> char_ptr
    | Some str -> str
 ;;

print_string test2;;
```

The pcap_lookupdev function returns either a string containing the device name or a null pointer. That bit seems to work fine (although I know my code is hardly idiomatic).

When writing this in C, you need to provide a character array to hold any error messages. So if a null pointer is returned, you should fail with the reason held in this character array. This character array should be "PCAP_ERRBUF_SIZE" long. However I can't figure out two things:

1. How to pull that constant size from the C library and create a string that size
2. Pass the string correctly to the function so that it gets correctly populated with the error message

Any help most gratefully appreciated :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For 1) the easiest way for getting #ifdef'd symbols into OCaml is to write a C program that outputs a seperate module with the value of these symbol. You then just use this module in your bindings when you need the symbols. You can find an example of this approach [here](https://github.com/dbuenzli/tsdl/tree/master/support).

For 2) I'd say ctypes's `string` is a little bit deceptive as it doesn't seem to act in a bidirectional fashion, that is you should only use it for `const char *` or return types. In this case you need to use arrays of character and then translate it to a string (this `char_array_as_string` function should be added to ctypes I [think](https://github.com/ocamllabs/ocaml-ctypes/issues/97)). Here's the full example, note that in future versions of ctypes the `Array` module will change its name to `CArray`:

```
(* Compile with: ocamlfind ocamlopt -package ctypes.foreign -linkpkg -cclib -lpcap \
                                    -o test.native test.ml *)

open Ctypes;;
open Foreign;;

module Pcap : sig
  val lookupdev : unit -> [ `Ok of string | `Error of string ]
end = struct

  let errbuf_size = 256 (* N.B. This should not be hardcoded, see 1) above *)

  let char_array_as_string a =
    let len = Array.length a in 
    let b = Buffer.create len in 
    try 
      for i = 0 to len -1 do 
        let c = Array.get a i in 
        if c = '\x00' then raise Exit else Buffer.add_char b c
      done;
      Buffer.contents b 
    with Exit -> Buffer.contents b

  let lookupdev = 
    foreign "pcap_lookupdev" (ptr char @-> returning string_opt)

  let lookupdev () =
    let err = Array.make char ~initial:'\x00' errbuf_size in
    match lookupdev (Array.start err) with 
    | None -> `Error (char_array_as_string err)
    | Some dev -> `Ok dev

end

let test () = match Pcap.lookupdev () with 
| `Ok dev -> Printf.printf "dev: %s\n" dev
| `Error err -> Printf.printf "error: %s\n" err

let () = test ()
```

Comment: Thank you for such a detailed and complete answer - no way would I have got this without your help. Thanks and Happy New Year! ;)