# Returning a string from a C library to OCaml using CTypes and Foreign

Tags: macos, ocaml, ffi

I'm having some trouble mapping native OSX calls from OCaml where the c call expects a buffer and size to be passed in. I've worked through the examples in Real World OCaml on using CTypes and Foreign but they don't cover this case or at least it's not clear to me how I'd to it.

Here's my snippet of OCaml:

```
open Core.Std
open Unix
open Ctypes
open Foreign

(* from /usr/include/libproc.h
  int proc_pidpath(int pid, void * buffer, uint32_t  buffersize);
*)
let proc_pidpath = foreign "proc_pidpath" (int @-> ptr void @-> int @-> returning int)

let () =
  let pid = Pid.to_int (Unix.getpid ()) in
  let buf = allocate string 255 in
  let path = proc_pidpath(pid, buf, 255) in
  printf "Pid: %i Path: %s\n" pid buf
```

How do I allocate a buffer to pass into `proc_pidpath()` and is there a nicer way of wrapping this call so it returns an Option type (String or Nil) or just a String?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This question share a lot of the issue with this [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20851390). I encourage you to have a look at it.

For your particular problem the following should work (it doesn't use `Core` so you may have to adjust some things, did they make the result of `Unix.getpid` abstract ?).

```
open Ctypes;;
open Foreign;;

module Proc : sig
  val pidpath : int -> string 
  (** @raise [Unix.Unix_error] in case of error *)
end = struct

  let pidpathinfo_maxsize = 1024 * 4 
  (* value of PROC_PIDPATHINFO_MAXSIZE. 
     N.B. this should not be hardcoded, see 1) in this answer 
     https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20851390 *)

  let char_array_as_string a len =    
  (* This function should soon no longer be required see:
     https://github.com/ocamllabs/ocaml-ctypes/pull/139 *)
    let b = Buffer.create len in 
    for i = 0 to len -1 do Buffer.add_char b (Array.get a i) done;
    Buffer.contents b

  let pidpath = 
    foreign ~check_errno:true "proc_pidpath"
      (int @-> ptr char @-> int @-> returning int)

  let pidpath pid =
    let path = Array.make char ~initial:'\x00' pidpathinfo_maxsize in 
    let len = pidpath pid (Array.start path) pidpathinfo_maxsize in
    char_array_as_string path len
end

let () =
  let print_pidpath pid = 
    try
      let path = Proc.pidpath pid in 
      Format.printf "Pid %d: %s@." pid path; 
    with Unix.Unix_error (e, _, _) -> 
      Format.eprintf "Pid %d: %s@." pid (Unix.error_message e)
  in
  print_pidpath (Unix.getpid ()); 
  print_pidpath (-10000 (* bogus *))
```

Comment: That works beautifully thanks. I think I got into trouble because I was looking for a `foreign` declaration that did the whole thing rather than doing some plumbing myself. Is there an idiomatic OCaml way of encoding the Unix.Unix_error into the method signature? Does wrapping it in an Option seem sensible?

Comment: For an exceptionless design I suggest this signature: `val pidpath : int -> [ ``Ok of string | ``Error of Unix.error ]` (two backticks should be a single one)

Comment: If you're having trouble getting this example to work, bear in mind that the Array above refers to the module in Ctypes, which was recently renamed to CArray.

Comment: One can now use `Ctypes.string_from_ptr char_ptr ~length`. And it seems one can use the coercion `coerce (ptr char) string` to convert a null-terminated string.